# Automation Testing for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, automated-tests

I was hoping you could point me in the correct direction.  I am trying to find an automation tool for an internal Chrome site that I, as a tester, can use to create tests.  I would prefer some kind of recording type option and free or very low cost.  And it MUST work on Chrome.  Our app doesn't work with any other browser

Here's what I've looked at so far:

- I am not going to have time to learn any new languages or have access to a developer, so Cucumber is out (this was the company's first choice).
- I found the Ghost add-on that records, but it needs to open the firewall to be used.  BIG no no.
- I looked at sikuli, but we can't have a dedicated screen like that, although it might still be a last ditch option
- TestComplete might work, but it costs money.  I am going to download the free trial, but the justification may not be enough to get the company to spend the money
- SoapUI is something I've worked with before and I know that only the Pro is helpful to a non-programmer like myself.

Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/). It is a keyword driven test automation framework and it has good Chrome support via Selenium. Web page has examples how to write tests for browsers.

Robot Framework is open source and free. Writing tests with keywords looks more difficult than using record-playback tool. However, once you have several tests, managing them will be easier with keywords.